# Sitecore - Export as HTML

Tags: html, xml, sitecore

I know about the Sitecore function to export Items to XML. But what I need is the complete HTML markup including permissions of the displayed pages in Sitecore.

Is there a way to export these out of Sitecore into XML?

Comment: There is no such feature out of the box. However you can write your own ones.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I entirely understand the question. If you simply want to export the pages of a website the easiest solution is to use a web scraping tool (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1041115/Webscraping-with-Csharp).

However I am uncertain about what you mean by "including permissions". Do you mean the security permissions set on the context item (the item/page being displayed)? If so then please note that a page can be composed by a context item and a lot of embedded data source items used in the various renderings which makes it a bit more tricky.

Cheers, Bo